# Does python-oracledb use the sqlnet.ora file?

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

Will attributes in Oracle Database's application-tier sqlnet.ora file get used by Oracle's new
[python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) driver?  This optional Oracle Net Services file can configure various
connection properties, including tracing, connection timeouts, keepalive times,
and network encryption.  For example what's the behavior if sqlnet.ora contains
this?:

```
sqlnet.outbound_connect_timeout=5
sqlnet.expire_time=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to Oracle Database in python-oracledb's default "thin" mode, any
sqlnet.ora file will **not** be read.  Instead many equivalent properties can be
set as connection parameters, for example:

```
connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs,
                              tcp_connect_timeout=10, expire_time=2)
```

See the user documentation [Creating a Standalone Connection](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#creating-a-standalone-connection).

Conversely, when python-oracledb Thick mode is enabled by calling
`oracledb.init_oracle_client()`, connecting in python-oracledb will read a
sqlnet.ora file if it exists.

See the user documentation on [optional configuration files](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files).

You can alternatively (in both modes) set many of these options in the `connect()` dsn parameter as an 'Easy Connection Plus' connection string, see the technical brief [Oracle Database 21c Easy Connect Plus](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-21c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf)